# Csr_matrix.dot vs. Numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large (*n=50000*) block diagonal `csr_matrix` **M** representing the adjacency matrices of a set of graphs. I have to have multiply **M** by a dense `numpy.array` **v** several times. Hence I use `M.dot(v)`.

Surprisingly, I have discovered that first converting **M** to `numpy.array` and then using `numpy.dot` is much faster.

Any ideas why this it the case?

Comment: Is `v` 1D vector? Or is it another `nxm` matrix? How sparse is your matrix? Sparse matrices are only as efficient as their sparsity factor. If your matrix is not *sparse* enough, arithmetic operations could be orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough memory to hold a `50000x50000` dense matrix in memory and multiply it by a `50000` vector. But find here some tests with lower dimensionality.

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def make_csr(n, N):
    rows = np.random.choice(N, n)
    cols = np.random.choice(N, n)
    data = np.ones(n)
    return csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(N,N), dtype=np.float32)
```

The code above generates sparse matrices with `n` non-zero elements in a `NxN` matrix.

Matrices:

```
N = 5000

# Sparse matrices
A = make_csr(10*10, N)     # ~100 non-zero
B = make_csr(100*100, N)   # ~10000 non-zero
C = make_csr(1000*1000, N) # ~1000000 non-zero
D = make_csr(5000*5000, N) # ~25000000 non-zero
E = csr_matrix(np.random.randn(N,N), dtype=np.float32) # non-sparse

# Numpy dense arrays
An = A.todense()
Bn = B.todense()
Cn = C.todense()
Dn = D.todense()
En = E.todense()

b = np.random.randn(N)
```

Timings:

```
>>> %timeit A.dot(b)       # 9.63 µs per loop
>>> %timeit An.dot(b)      # 41.6 ms per loop

>>> %timeit B.dot(b)       # 41.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit Bn.dot(b)      # 41.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit C.dot(b)       # 3.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit Cn.dot(b)      # 41.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit D.dot(b)       # 35.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit Dn.dot(b)      # 43.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit E.dot(b)       # 55.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit En.dot(b)      # 43.4 ms per loop
```

- For *highly sparse* matrices (`A` and `B`) it is more than `1000x` times faster.
- For *not very sparse* matrices (`C`), it still gets `10x` speedup.
- For *almost non-sparse* matrix (`D` will have some `0` due to repetition in the indices, but not many probabilistically speaking), it is still faster, not much, but faster.
- For a truly *non-sparse* matrix (`E`), the operation is slower, but not much slower.

**Conclusion:** the speedup you get depends on the *sparsity* of your matrix, but with `N = 5000` sparse matrices are *always* faster (as long as they have some *zero* entries).

I can't try it for `N = 50000` due to memory issues. You can try the above code and see what is like for you with that `N`.

Comment: The reason why `np.dot` is so much faster for small matrices is that it typically calls a BLAS function to do the actual multiplication. Depending on what BLAS library your version of numpy is linked to, these are often multithreaded and very heavily optimised. `csr_dot` is single-threaded, and as your timings show, only shows efficiency gains when dealing with highly sparse matrices. BTW, `sparse.rand` is an easier way to create random sparse matrices with variable density.

Comment: @ali_m Thank you very much, didn't know about `sparse.rand`. Btw, I have numpy linked to OpenBLAS.

Comment: OpenBLAS is very fast indeed - most benchmarks place it on par with (or slightly faster than) Intel MKL (e.g. [here](http://gcdart.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/fast-matrix-multiply-and-ml.html)).

Comment: @ali_m wow thanks for the detailed comparison. Atm I don't have access to more than 8 cores though :/